# How do I create a new single column based on multiple regex against multiple other columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe with multiple columns of strings. I want to

1. look at all strings in a series of these columns
2. see if any strings match an input pattern, ideally `regex`
3. create a single new binary column that is equal to 1 or TRUE if there are any matches across all columns for a given row, and 0 or FALSE if there are no matches whatsoever.

My question has two parts.

First, I am using `sapply` and `grepl` and have managed to create a dataframe of TRUE/FALSE values for all of the columns in question, but am having trouble figuring out how to get to the "create a new single column" step. I tried `rowwise` mutate but that's throwing errors that I honestly don't understand!

```r
df <- data.frame(
  idx = 1:5,
  column_b = letters[1:5],
  column_c = c('abc', 'abc', 'def', 'def', 'ghi'), 
  column_d = c('def', 'def', 'def', 'def', 'def'),
  column_e = c('ghi', 'ghi', 'ghi', 'abc', 'ghi')
)

apply_factor <- function(df, factor, col_low, col_high, pattern) {
   df %>%
   rowwise() %>%
   mutate(factor = sum(c_across(as.data.frame(sapply(select(df, {{col_low}}:{{col_high}}), grepl, pattern={{pattern}})))), na.rm = TRUE)
}

apply_factor(df, factor = 'abc', 'column_c', 'column_e', pattern = "^abc")
```

(double curly braces `{{}}` in the function due to something or other about `dplyr` I saw in another question...)

Console responds:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `factor = sum(...)`.
i The error occurred in row 1.
Caused by error in `as_indices_impl()`:
! Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
x Subscript has the wrong type `data.frame<
  column_c: logical
  column_d: logical
  column_e: logical
>`.
i It must be numeric or character.
```

If I run just the as.data.frame() part it gives me something that looks pretty good. I just need to make it into a new column!

```
> as.data.frame(sapply(select(df, 'column_c':'column_e'), grepl, pattern = "^abc"))

  column_c column_d column_e
1     TRUE    FALSE    FALSE
2     TRUE    FALSE    FALSE
3    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE
4    FALSE    FALSE     TRUE
5    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE
```

Second, I need to extend this function to a much larger dataset with many millions of rows and between 30 and 100 string columns. The large and variable number of columns, by the way, is why I need this function to be able to take any range of columns instead of listing out every possible column. Since processing time will be somewhat of a factor: is what I am doing here going to be massively inefficient? Is there an easier, faster way to accomplish this?

I've tried variations on sum, `summarise`, and any, but honestly it's very likely I did it wrong.

I also looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39405628/how-do-i-create-a-new-column-based-on-multiple-conditions-from-multiple-columns?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top), but I can't limit to using `%in%` as I need regex (I'm *pretty* sure I can't use regex with %in%...)

(I am relearning R after a long stint away in Stata-land, so please forgive any really obvious blunders or terminology weirdness!)

Comment: Hi, yes it works! Followup, if you don't mind: I'm now trying to call this function with an item from a list, e.g. `col = a_list[1]`, and I'm getting an error:
`Error in local_error_context(dots = dots, .index = i, mask = mask) : 
promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?`
I read this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357101/promise-already-under-evaluation-recursive-default-argument-reference-or-earlie) and I'm guessing it has something to do with the := in the function? Any insights?

Comment: I need to know how you define `a_list`. Maybe changing `{{col}} :=` to `!!sym(col) :=` will work. See my update.

Comment: That works, thank you so much! My list was just `a_list <-c("abc", "def", "ghi")`, for example. 
I [read a little](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68984415/what-does-operator-mean-in-r) about {{}} and !!, but could you explain why the sym() part is necessary?

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57136322/10068985) may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grepl` is vectorized, so you can use it with `if_any()`, which is much faster than `rowwise`.

```r
df %>%
  mutate(abc = if_any(column_c:column_e, ~ grepl("^abc", .x)))

#   idx column_b column_c column_d column_e   abc
# 1   1        a      abc      def      ghi  TRUE
# 2   2        b      abc      def      ghi  TRUE
# 3   3        c      def      def      ghi FALSE
# 4   4        d      def      def      abc  TRUE
# 5   5        e      ghi      def      ghi FALSE
```

To wrap the code in a function:

```r
ifany_grepl <- function(data, col, lower, upper, pattern) {
  data %>%
    mutate(!!sym(col) := if_any({{lower}}:{{upper}}, ~ grepl(pattern, .x)))
}

ifany_grepl(df, 'abc', 'column_c', 'column_e', "^abc")
```